# plot data from more than one text file using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two files. `Xdata.txt` And `Ydata.txt`.
Each row of `Xdata` should be plotted versus each row of `Ydata`.
The point is that number of column in each row is different.
For example:

**Xdata.txt**:

```
row1: 1 2 3 4 5 6
row2: 1 2 3 4
```

**Ydata.txt**:

```
row1: 1 2 3 4 5 6
row2: 1 2 3 4
```

And I want to plot

`Xdata[row1], Ydata[row1]`

`Xdata=[row2], Ydata[row2]`

in a one figure. Please help me with this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the process by loading each file into a list.

```
with open("Xdata.txt", "r") as xf:
    x_list = xf.readlines()

with open("Ydata.txt", "r") as yf:
    y_list = yf.readlines()
```

Then, you make use of python's `zip` function to grab each pair of lines and plot them. This will pair line 1 in Xdata.txt with line 1 in Ydata.txt and so on:

```
for (x_line, y_line) in zip(x_list, y_list):
    # Split out the data from the line, which is stored as a string
    x_data = x_line.split(' ')
    y_data = y_line.split(' ')

    # Insert data conversion from string to numbers if needed

    # Modify plotting code as needed
    plot(x_data, y_data)
```

Comment: Hi;  I got :
for (x_line, y_line) in zip(x_list, y_list):
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: @mohammad24 my mistake, it should be `readlines()`, not `readlines`. Try printing the lists out to see if that's what you expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this (An implementation of @jrmylow answer):

**Input**:

```
Xdata.txt 

1 4 3 6 5 6
1 2 3 7

Ydata.txt 

1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
with open("Xdata.txt", "r") as xf:
    x_list = xf.readlines()

with open("Ydata.txt", "r") as yf:
    y_list = yf.readlines()

for (x_line, y_line) in zip(x_list, y_list):
    x_data = x_line.split(' ')
    y_data = y_line.split(' ')
    plt.plot(x_data, y_data)

plt.legend(['first','second'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it works for you.